# Cool Alternatives to HTML Checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, checkbox, radio-button

ok not just checkbox, but also radio button. The thing is I have a zillion check-boxes & radio-buttons on my form & it looks ugly as hell.

This is not a functionality issue but a purely UI issue. I am looking for some cooler looking ways to implement the same task.

Oh I am using jQuery 1.4.3

**UPDATE: I got this [jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-checkbox/) for the same. It's awesome!! Thanks all...** Attached the screenshot of the one I am using now. This one I liked because, it kinda looks like a iPhone style but is not an exact clone.

[image]

Comment: Um, you tagged the post jQuery UI.  Aren't you using jQuery UI radios and checkboxes?  They look great...  Unless maybe you mis-tagged this question?

Comment: It's not always "the same task". You're going to need to be more specific.

Comment: "same task" as in do what check-boxes & radio-buttons do. there is no functionality change. I am just interested in better ways to present them... meaning UI

Comment: @stephen the ones jQuery provides make sure that your checkboxes & radio buttons look uniformly (ugly) in all browsers. It's not a better looking alternative to normal ones...

Comment: Providing a screenshot or sample might improve suggestions. "Ugly" often isn't only in the graphics, but how contents is arranged and related.

Comment: @MovieYoda The jQuery UI elements can be re-styled any way you want.  Just because the default theme-roller doesn't fit your style doesn't mean you have to use it.  You can make your own style sheet that styles the `ui-*` classes that are added to the widgets.

Comment: quoting @elusive (from the answers comment). "It's not that easy to re-skin checkboxes/radio buttons using CSS & trying to maintain same look & feel across. There are issues with borders, colors, etc. If you know how to tackle this problem please provide an answer or atleast some links

Comment: @MovieYoda: Alright, then. I posted an example below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't a drop-down menu work to replace many check-boxes/radio buttons? You could enable multiple selections to replecate check box behaviour. Generally that is what I would do if I had more than one or two check boxes on the same subject...

Or do you mean they are about separate things? In that case, could you post some idea of what information you're trying to get from the user?

Comment: It is an interesting idea to replace multiple checkboxes with multi-selects. Makes sense. +1.

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly more advanced task than changing the border of edit-fields. The best method would be to hide the checkbox/radiobutton and replacing it with a dummy element. The problem with this approach is to keep both elements synced. The radiobutton-image needs to know when another radiobutton has been checked, etc. This requires some advanced event-ping-pong. You could do it like this for checkboxes (untested):

```
$(':checkbox').each(function () {
   var checkbox = $(this),
      fakebox = $(document.createElement('span')).addClass('custom-checkbox');

   // toggle and trigger update of the real checkbox
   fakebox.click(function () {
      checkbox.attr('checked', !checkbox.attr('checked')).change();
   });

   // changes to the real checkbox causes the fake checkbox to update its status
   checkbox.change(function () {
      if (checkbox.attr('checked')) {
         fakebox.addClass('custom-checkbox-checked');
      } else {
         fakebox.removeClass('custom-checkbox-checked');
      }
   });

   // initialize
   checkbox.change().hide();
   fakebox.insertAfter(checkbox);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always re-skin the checkboxes/radio buttons using CSS (just like any other form element such as buttons).

Comment: It is not _that_ easy, actually. Checkboxes/radiobuttons have issues with borders, colors, etc in various browsers.